# Trying to retrieve data from multiple related tables in mysql from very big data

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this question has been asked several time, but I been trying to get data from many to many related multiple tables in mysql table. Also, each table contains minimum of 500000 records. How can speed up the data retrieving process in this case ?

Although, I have try to get data using group by to prepare data according to screen but it still working very slow.

In controller of screen I have used group by using linq.

```
var lstclientId = (from c in DBContext.groupmasters.Where(w => w.isactive == true && w.UserID == userid)
                   group c by c.ClientID into d
                   select new
                   {
                       clientID = d.Key,
                   });


var lstJobTypeID = (from c in DBContext.jobrequisitions.Where(w => w.ISActive == true)
                    group c by new { c.CreativeID, c.ProjectName, c.client.ClientName, c.brandmaster.branddesc } into d
                    select new
                    {
                        CreativeID = d.Key.CreativeID,
                        ProjectName = d.Key.ProjectName,
                        ClientName = d.Key.ClientName,
                        branddesc = d.Key.branddesc,
                    }).OrderBy(o => o.CreativeID);
List<jobrequisition> lstrequisition = new List<jobrequisition>();
List<jobrequisition> lstrequisitionusers = new List<jobrequisition>();
if ((Session["deptCode"]).ToString() == "QC" || (Session["deptCode"]).ToString() == "OP" || Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsAdmin"]) == true)
{
    database2Entities JobEntities = new database2Entities();
    lstrequisition = JobEntities.jobrequisitions.Where(w => w.ISActive == true).ToList();
    lstrequisitionusers.AddRange(lstrequisition);
}
else
{
    foreach (var i in lstclientId)
    {
        database2Entities JobEntities = new database2Entities();
        lstrequisition = JobEntities.jobrequisitions.Where(w => w.ISActive == true && w.ClientID == i.clientID).ToList();
        lstrequisitionusers.AddRange(lstrequisition);
    }
}
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
int k = 0;
foreach (var i in lstJobTypeID)
{
    foreach (jobrequisition objRequestion in lstrequisitionusers.OrderBy(o => o.CreativeID))
    {
        if (objRequestion.CreativeID == i.CreativeID)
        {
            database2Entities ArtContext = new database2Entities();
            database2Entities SubArtContext = new database2Entities();
            if (lstArtWorkReqID.Count() == 0)
            {

                ///old code... 
                var lstArt = ArtContext.artworkrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT *, count(ArtWorkName) as awtname FROM artworkrequisition as awt group by ArtWorkID having CreativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1").ToList();
                foreach (artworkrequisition art in lstArt)
                {
                    int isCompletedcount = 0, assigncount = 0, allitemcount = 0, jobassignedcount = 0, iscompletedjobcount = 0;
                    List<artworkrequisition> allartworkitems = SubArtContext.artworkrequisitions.Where(w => w.ArtWorkID == art.ArtWorkID && w.IsActive == true).ToList();
                    jobassignedcount = allartworkitems.Where(w => w.isAssigned == true).Count();
                    allitemcount = allartworkitems.Where(w => w.IsActive == true).Count();
                    if (jobassignedcount > 0)
                    {
                        if (jobassignedcount <= allitemcount)
                        {
                            foreach (artworkrequisition singleartitem in allartworkitems)
                            {
                                if (singleartitem.isAssigned == null && singleartitem.isAssigned == true)
                                {
                                    job_assigned_employee allocatedjobdetails = SubArtContext.job_assigned_employee.Where(w => w.ItemJobReqID == singleartitem.Id && w.JobTypeID == 1 && w.JobReqNo == singleartitem.ArtWorkID && w.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (allocatedjobdetails.IsCompelete == true)
                                    {
                                        iscompletedjobcount += 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (iscompletedjobcount < allitemcount)
                            {
                                lstArtWorkReqID.Add(art);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstArtWorkReqID.Add(art);
                    }
                }



            }
            else
            {
                var lstArt = ArtContext.artworkrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT *, count(ArtWorkName) awtname FROM artworkrequisition awt group by ArtWorkID having CreativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1").ToList();
                foreach (artworkrequisition art in lstArt)
                {
                    int isCompletedcount = 0, assigncount = 0, allitemcount = 0, jobassignedcount = 0, iscompletedjobcount = 0;
                    List<artworkrequisition> allartworkitems = SubArtContext.artworkrequisitions.Where(w => w.ArtWorkID == art.ArtWorkID && w.IsActive == true).ToList();
                    jobassignedcount = allartworkitems.Where(w => w.isAssigned == true).Count();
                    allitemcount = allartworkitems.Where(w => w.IsActive == true).Count();
                    if (jobassignedcount > 0)
                    {
                        if (jobassignedcount <= allitemcount)
                        {
                            foreach (artworkrequisition singleartitem in allartworkitems)
                            {
                                if (singleartitem.isAssigned != null && singleartitem.isAssigned == true)
                                {
                                    job_assigned_employee allocatedjobdetails = SubArtContext.job_assigned_employee.Where(w => w.ItemJobReqID == singleartitem.Id && w.JobTypeID == 1 && w.JobReqNo == singleartitem.ArtWorkID && w.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (allocatedjobdetails != null)
                                    {
                                        if (allocatedjobdetails.IsCompelete != null && allocatedjobdetails.IsCompelete == true)
                                        {
                                            iscompletedjobcount += 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (iscompletedjobcount <= jobassignedcount && iscompletedjobcount != allitemcount)
                            {
                                lstArtWorkReqID.Add(art);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstArtWorkReqID.Add(art);
                    }

                    //         job_assigned_employee allocatedjobdetails = SubArtContext.job_assigned_employee.Where(w => w.ItemJobReqID == singleartitem.Id && w.JobTypeID == 1 && w.JobReqNo == singleartitem.ArtWorkID && w.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault();

                }
            }
            if (lstPhotoStockReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstPhotoStock = ArtContext.photographyrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM photographyrequisition where CreativeNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1  and isApproved = 0 group by photographyReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (photographyrequisition objphot in lstPhotoStock)
                {
                    lstPhotoStockReq.Add(objphot);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                var lstPhotoStock = ArtContext.photographyrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM photographyrequisition where CreativeNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1  and isApproved = 0 group by photographyReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (photographyrequisition objphot in lstPhotoStock)
                {
                    lstPhotoStockReq.Add(objphot);
                }
            }
            if (lstInterActiveWorkReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstinteractivereq = ArtContext.interactiverequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM interactiverequisition where CreativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 group by InteractiveID").ToList();
                foreach (interactiverequisition objInter in lstinteractivereq)
                {
                    lstInterActiveWorkReq.Add(objInter);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                var lstinteractivereq = ArtContext.interactiverequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM interactiverequisition where CreativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 group by InteractiveID").ToList();
                foreach (interactiverequisition objInter in lstinteractivereq)
                {
                    lstInterActiveWorkReq.Add(objInter);
                }
            }
            if (lstTransWorkReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstTranslatereq = ArtContext.translationrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM translationrequisition where creativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by TransReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (translationrequisition objTrans in lstTranslatereq)
                {
                    lstTransWorkReq.Add(objTrans);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstTranslatereq = ArtContext.translationrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM translationrequisition where creativeID = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1  and isApproved = 0 group by TransReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (translationrequisition objTrans in lstTranslatereq)
                {
                    lstTransWorkReq.Add(objTrans);
                }
            }
            if (lstPrintProductionReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstPrintProductReq = ArtContext.printproductionrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM printproductionrequisition where CampaingNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by PrintProductionReqID").ToList();
                foreach (printproductionrequisition objPrint in lstPrintProductReq)
                {
                    lstPrintProductionReq.Add(objPrint);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstPrintProductReq = ArtContext.printproductionrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM printproductionrequisition where CampaingNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by PrintProductionReqID").ToList();
                foreach (printproductionrequisition objPrint in lstPrintProductReq)
                {
                    lstPrintProductionReq.Add(objPrint);
                }
            }

            if (lstFilmProductionReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstFilmproductionReq = ArtContext.filmproductionrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM filmproductionrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by FilmProductionReqID").ToList();
                foreach (filmproductionrequisition objFilm in lstFilmproductionReq)
                {
                    lstFilmProductionReq.Add(objFilm);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstFilmproductionReq = ArtContext.filmproductionrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM filmproductionrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by FilmProductionReqID").ToList();
                foreach (filmproductionrequisition objFilm in lstFilmproductionReq)
                {
                    lstFilmProductionReq.Add(objFilm);
                }
            }

            if (lstRetainerFeeReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstRetainerfeereq = ArtContext.retainerfeerequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM retainerfeerequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by RetainerfeeReqID").ToList();
                foreach (retainerfeerequisition objRetainer in lstRetainerfeereq)
                {
                    lstRetainerFeeReq.Add(objRetainer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstRetainerfeereq = ArtContext.retainerfeerequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM retainerfeerequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by RetainerfeeReqID").ToList();
                foreach (retainerfeerequisition objRetainer in lstRetainerfeereq)
                {
                    lstRetainerFeeReq.Add(objRetainer);
                }
            }

            if (lstStockImageReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstStockImagereq = ArtContext.stockimagerequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM stockimagerequisition where CampaginNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1  and isApproved = 0 and statusId = 4 group by StockImageReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (stockimagerequisition objStockImage in lstStockImagereq)
                {
                    lstStockImageReq.Add(objStockImage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstStockImagereq = ArtContext.stockimagerequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM stockimagerequisition where CampaginNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1  and isApproved = 0 and statusId = 4 group by StockImageReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (stockimagerequisition objStockImage in lstStockImagereq)
                {
                    lstStockImageReq.Add(objStockImage);
                }
            }

            if (lstSystemWorkReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstSystemWork = ArtContext.systemworkrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM systemworkrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1 and StatusID = 4 group by SystemReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (systemworkrequisition systemwork in lstSystemWork)
                {
                    lstSystemWorkReq.Add(systemwork);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstSystemWork = ArtContext.systemworkrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM systemworkrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1 and StatusID = 4 group by SystemReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (systemworkrequisition systemwork in lstSystemWork)
                {
                    lstSystemWorkReq.Add(systemwork);
                }
            }

            if (lstOthersReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstOthersreq = ArtContext.othersrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM othersrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by OtherReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (othersrequisition objOthers in lstOthersreq)
                {
                    lstOthersReq.Add(objOthers);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstOthersreq = ArtContext.othersrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM othersrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by OtherReqNo").ToList();
                foreach (othersrequisition objOthers in lstOthersreq)
                {
                    lstOthersReq.Add(objOthers);
                }
            }


            if (lstTenderReq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstTendersreq = ArtContext.tender_noticerequisition.SqlQuery("SELECT *, count(TenderNoticeName) as tendername FROM tender_noticerequisition as awt group by tendernoticeID having CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1").ToList();
                foreach (tender_noticerequisition objTenders in lstTendersreq)
                {
                    lstTenderReq.Add(objTenders);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstTendersreq = ArtContext.tender_noticerequisition.SqlQuery("SELECT *, count(TenderNoticeName) as tendername FROM tender_noticerequisition as awt group by tendernoticeID having CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and IsActive = 1").ToList();
                foreach (tender_noticerequisition objTenders in lstTendersreq)
                {
                    lstTenderReq.Add(objTenders);
                }
            }


            if (lstillustrationreq.Count() == 0)
            {
                var lstillustrareq = ArtContext.illustrationrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT *,count(descriptions) FROM illustrationrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by IllustrationNo").ToList();
                foreach (illustrationrequisition objillustra in lstillustrareq)
                {
                    lstillustrationreq.Add(objillustra);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lstillustrareq = ArtContext.illustrationrequisitions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM illustrationrequisition where CampaignNo = '" + i.CreativeID + "' and isActive = 1 and isApproved = 0 group by IllustrationNo").ToList();
                foreach (illustrationrequisition objillustra in lstillustrareq)
                {
                    lstillustrationreq.Add(objillustra);
                }
            }

            string strprojectClient = i.ProjectName + "-" + i.ClientName + "-" + i.branddesc;
            ht.Add(i.CreativeID, strprojectClient);
            k++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get data like this

> campaign no :100001 -> job no: 1001 entry date: 28-03-2019

Comment: You have big and un-wielding code, using entity framework. To make it fast, do the following break in to smaller parallel units, which can be executed as isolated async calls, do all logical processing in the application server and your code will be much more faster. Use Dapper instead of EF, that's much more lean meant for performance

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I am trying to break down DB call into the chunks but could you help me out how can start with dapper in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you change:

```
from c in DBContext.jobrequisitions.Where(w => w.ISActive == true)
```

to something like

```
from c in DBContext.jobrequisitions
where c.ISActive == true
```

You might improve the performance a little bit, because, as far as I remember, the fluent version `Where` will execute as a separate query to the database, instead as part of the group by query, thus causing the database to generate a less efficient execution plan.

By the way, as a side note, I'd recommend not mixing between the SQL and fluent LINQ query syntaxes unless absolutely necessary.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I really appreciate you promptly commenting on my query. Actually, I'm trying to use less linq code and get an data in one call itself. In the above scenario the  'jobrequisitions' table contains all campaigns and job type relationship. Each campaign has different job type ids, accordingly i have get job details from different job type tables. eg. campaign no: 10001, has job type 1 & 2 based on job type 1 = artworkrequisition table data and base on job type 2 filmrequisition table data has to get. but data is so huge.

Comment: Then I think it's even more important for you to move the where functionality inside the group query, as the database should be much more efficient when it performs both the `where` clause and the `group by` clause in the same query.